# Broken Image in Safari Browser of my macbook takes full height unlike chrome and firefox

Tags: css, image, safari, height

I found a weird issue while testing my application in safari(Version 13.1).
Basically, an image in the website is broken and it's not loaded.
Chrome and FireFox are showing the `alt` attribute's value and occupies the least height possible for the unloaded image tag.
But safari browser in my mac occupies way more height than others and having a weird user experience pushing the  tag to bottom.

Here is the reproduction of the issue - https://jsfiddle.net/etjhgpdo/1/ - Open this url in both chrome and safari. We can see the difference that heading tag is pushed down as the image tag's height is so much in safari.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on safari the default of broken image is width:100%; height:auto; so it's kinda full width depending of its container. and on sfari the alt text will only show if the width of the image is large enough to accommodate it. If no width is specified for the img, the alt text may not be displayed at all

Comment: The problem for me is with height. How to fix broken image's height in safari? Can we make it like how chrome or firefox work for this issue?

Comment: You nedd to set the height explicitly

Comment: @ZiadDarwich Yeah.. I found a workaround like  `onerror="this.style.height = '50px'"` on the image tag. This can help. 
But need to see if there's any safari specific css styling with a pseudo selector like failed or error for a image tag to apply the styles.

Comment: maybe you can check the navigator if its safari or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't receive any answer, I am adding the workaround fix I found on web.
Addding `onerror="this.style.height = '50px'"` on the image tag helped me in reducing the height. 
But this will apply to all the browsers as we are not specifying any browser here.